# What is the best way check whether statement is tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For example I have a statement : $(c\implies a) \lor (\neg a\implies b)$ .
Is there anyway to know whether this statement is tautology or not without assignment binary value 0,1 to each variable ( or if we have 100 variables , can we know this is tautology without 2^100 times check every possibility combinations) ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Effective method: [Truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). Efficient: No; see [Satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)

Comment: Short-cut method: try to find a falsifying assignment. In the above example, a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(c \to a)=v(\lnot a \to b)= \text F$ . If you find a contradiction, the formula is a tautology.

Comment: This is more like a programming question. Did you google it at least? You should  look here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250675/how-to-create-an-algorithm-for-determining-boolean-tautologies

Comment: The way this question was asked initially implied: "how do I do it by paper and pencil", then suddenly "I need to write a program" popped up.

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/ is a tool to find this out. Y>ou may check the references on this page for algorithms to do this.

Comment: For statements with $100$ variables, you will want to use a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver).  Writing one is not an easy programming project, but good ones such as MiniSAT are freely available.

Comment: Short (indirect) truth-table method, truth-trees, resolution, and Davis-Putnam are all well-known methods to try and do this more efficiently than a full truth-table, but in the end this is an NP-complete problem with the worst case as you indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rework the logical expression just like you rework algebraic expressions. If at the end you get TRUE/FALSE (i.e. you get a value which does not depend on any variable), then the initial formula was a tautology or a contradiction.

E.g. you can rework any expression into

[Disjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

If you have algebraic expression e.g. $f(x,y) = ... $ one way to check if it's a constant is to rework it (simplify it) and see if you get a constant at the end. Same approach is possible here in propositional logic.

Comment: Because i want to write a program to check a statement is tautology or not , so i dont think rework the logical experession is a good ideal

Comment: @TheHo Why not a good idea?

Comment: Aha . Understood

Comment: You should google something like this "algorithm to check if a logical formula is a tautology".

Answer (score 0):

If you transform the equation into [conjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)/[disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) normal form, if it is a tautology, all terms will reduce to true. Depending how the original statement looks like one or the other might be preferable.

To quickly check it on paper you might use something like a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).